Fail to deploy Angular project on Cloudflare Pages
I tried to deploy my Angular project from my Github repository with Cloudflare free plan.
But failed. How can I success deploy?
About project:

The project doesn't include SSR or SSG.
I added .nvmrc to project.

Build settings on cloudflare is default:
Build command:
npm run build
Build output directory:
/dist/cloudflare
Build system version:
2 (latest)
Root directory:
/
Environment variables:
None
This is last part of build log:
11:57:04.079    Finished
11:57:04.079    Note: No functions dir at /functions found. Skipping.
11:57:04.080    Validating asset output directory
11:57:04.080    Error: Output directory "dist/cloudflare" not found.
11:57:05.266    Failed: build output directory not found
My project doesn't have "dist" directory.

Try setting your build command to: npx ng build --verbose --output-path dist/cloudflare
Edit: --verbose is optional.

It looks like adding the following to your Cloudflare page build configuration found in 
Settings>Build>Build Configuration

fixes the deployment issue
and any subsequent 404 error you may get once the page deploys.
Build command:
npx ng build --verbose --output-path dist/cloudflare

Build output:
dist/cloudflare/browser

Optionally you can change your package.json build command to be:
npx ng build --verbose --output-path dist/cloudflare 

and leave the cloudflare build command to the deafult of ng build.
If you are building successfully but getting a 404 change the build output to dist/cloudflare/browser
